# Drush cannot locate mysql on localhost MAMP

Tags: mamp, drupal-8, drush

Using drush commands to update Drupal 8 Core on a localhost build in MAMP, I've found that drush won't acknowledge my mysql.

From reading a few threads apparently this is due to MAMP's default locations for MYSQL location not being compatible with drush's expectation.

I've followed a few forum suggestions for fixed but so far have not had any luck.

The Latest attempt gives me this permission error:

```
 [warning] The command 'mysql' is required for preflight but cannot be found. 
Please install it and retry. Drush Commandline Tool 9.2.3
```

Other attempts:

I followed the suggestion from March 14th on this thread:

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3464

which gave me this error:

> [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_iBYWVg --database=drupal20180405 --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent < /private/tmp/drush_7T1mwj [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_bvCyn3 --database=drupal20180405 --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent < /private/tmp/drush_a9aRha In Connection.php line 149: [PDOException (2002)] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Another potential solution I tried came from Chrisblomm's answer on this thread:

[Drush cannot connect to MySQL on MAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300996/drush-cannot-connect-to-mysql-on-mamp)

Unfortunately for me that triggered the first error again:

```
 [warning] The command 'mysql' is required for preflight but cannot be found. 
Please install it and retry. Drush Commandline Tool 9.2.3
```

**UPDATE: I found a solution here:**

Andrew Patton's comments on this thread solved it for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990624/2639928

Specifically his tips to "define and export mysql and mysqladmin as functions".

Once I added his suggested lines of code to  to my Mac's local .bash_profile it then allowed drush to correctly identify the mysql.

This meant I was able to use all the drush commands I needed that had previously triggered drush errors.

Comment: perhaps you should post those errors otherwise it could be anything and you will get just wild guesses

Comment: Hi GiorgoksK, here is the error I receive:
 [warning] The command 'mysql' is required for preflight but cannot be found. Please install it and retry.
Drush Commandline Tool 9.2.3

Comment: I followed this suggestion:
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3464
which gave more errors:
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_iBYWVg --database=drupal20180405 --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_7T1mwj
 [info] Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_bvCyn3 --database=drupal20180405 --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_a9aRha
In Connection.php line 149:
                            
  [PDOException (2002)]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: I also tried Chrisblomm's steps in this post, but that just gave me the original error again:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300996/drush-cannot-connect-to-mysql-on-mamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Patton's comments here solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990624/2639928
specifically his tips to "define and export mysql and mysqladmin as functions"
once I added that to my mac / user / .bash_profile my drush acknowledged the mysql and I was able to use all the commands I needed that had previously given me drush errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in my php container

```
 [warning] The shell command 'mysql' is required but cannot be found. Please install it and retry.
```

The mysql client was not installed  so to fix it I added mysql client

```
apt-get install -y default-mysql-client
```