# How does symlinking work in linux

Tags: python, linux, django

I installed django framework and going through the documentation I was instructed to run the django-admin.py but threw an error:

```
Command not found
```

I was Instructed in the documentation to try symlinking to django-admin.py from some place on my path such as

```
 /usr/local/bin
```

which has left me totally confused because I'm kind of new to linux

Comment: How did you install django? What distribution are you using?

Comment: Also, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *symlink* is a **symbolic link**. What you're doing is telling the operating system that, when a request comes in for path x, to treat it as path y.

So, if django wants a file at '/expected/path/to/file', but the file is really at '/actual/path', you would build the symlink so that request to the first are instead fulfilled by going to the second. The syntax would be:

```
ln -s /actual/path/to/file /expected/path/to/file
```

otherwise broken down as `link` command, `symbolic` option, `target` path, `symbolic` path.

Comment: looks like @runnerup got to the heart of it while I was jabbering :)

Comment: it is actually `ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME`. you got it the other way around

Comment: I did, what a bonehead move. Thanks for noticing.