# why idle in virtualenv keeps using system one?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-idle

I have create a local python installation in ~/localpython/python276
After create a virtualenv as py276, I linked the idle to `~/localpython/python276
/bin/idle`. I also activated the py276.

```
$ which python
/home/xxx/virtualenvs/py276/bin/python

$ python
Python 2.7.6 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


$ bin/idle
Python 2.7.6
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

All things seems correct. However, if I just use `idle` as command, it will still use system one, which does not make any sense because `which idle` returns the correct result.

```
$ which idle
/home/xxx/virtualenvs/py276/bin/idle
$ idle
Python 2.7.3
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `idle` typed alone on the command line is actually a symbolic link to the 2.7.3 installed version. You must either change the symbolic link or be more explicit with your command.

[Symbolic Link(symlink) Definition.](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/symblink.htm)

[How to symlink a file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux)

Comment: sorry I cannot accept the answer. As I mentioned in original post, the /home/xxx/virtualenvs/py276/bin/idle will call the correct python version.

Comment: Exactly, when you are more explicit and you type the literal path to the idle inside py276 it works, but `idle` alone on the command line is taken to mean the symbolic link for idle in the path section of your .bashrc which is pointing to an installation of Python2.7.3.

Comment: I cannot understand you. In your post, you said I may link the bin/idle to a wrong version of python. But it is not true, as I said before. Now you said the idle command are still associate with system idle. But as I mentioned in the original post: `$ which idle` gives 
`/home/xxx/virtualenvs/py276/bin/idle`, which is not pointing to py273.