# How to change /etc/localtime to a symbolic link debian

Tags: java, debian

I had some issues associated with this bug
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6609348

and one of the workarounds as it says on that page, is 
`Change /etc/localtime to a symbolic link again`, but what does that mean and how to do that ? I am using Debian 7.

Thanks

Comment: I had to google a little bit more ((( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux

Comment: If you found an answer, maybe add it for other people?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, in general I always do, but because i had to simply re-post the answer from another question, just decided to leave a comment, so other users after all can follow it. thanks