# Alternative for symlink

Tags: php, symlink

Is there any alternative function for symlink() to user in shared hosting servers that prevent symlink for security reasons?
or at least how can i get the source code for this function?

Comment: Give some details on what specific error message you ran into. (No, there isn't an alternative PHP userland implementation for this system function. Use SSH or SFTP, or craft a CGI workaround if available.)

Comment: the server auto delete php files that contain symlink function

Comment: If you can't provide a more precise decription, then please consult your hosting provider instead.

Comment: symlink() has been disabled for security reasons on line ??

Comment: and in php.ini there is a line 
disable_functions = 'disk_free_space,disk_total_space,diskfreespace,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,exec,highlight_file,link,passthru,popen,proc_close,prog_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,set_time_limit,shell_exec,show_source,symlink,system,tmpfile,tempnam'

Comment: and hosting provider cannot remove this function from disable_functions list

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a exec command instead.

```
exec('ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink');
```

[How to symlink a file in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux) goes into more details about doing server side symlinks.