# Site redirection and dsplayed site address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I purchased a domain name, newfestivals.com, which I redirected to a subdirectory of another site I manage, myexistingsite.com/newfestivals. All works fine, but I would like to display www.newfestivals.com in the address bar, not myexistingsite.com/newfestivals.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: They are on different servers?

Comment: @dgig they are on the same server

Comment: @AmitThakur I have tried .htaccess with no luck. 
`RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newfestivals\.com$ RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.newfestivals\.com$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.myexistingsite\.com\/newfestivals\/$1" [P,L] `

Comment: If they're on the same server, you might be able to link the content using a symlink to recreate the folder in the other location you need it at. Avoiding all htaccess business. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux

Comment: @dgig Thank you, I hadn't thought of that, I will try it and report back.

Comment: How can that help me though? I want users to type www.newfestivals.com and have that also stay in the address bar when displaying www.myexistingsite.com/newfestival contents. Where should I put the symlink?

Answer (score 0):

For the symlink, generally I set it up like this:

```
  ┣ newfestivals.com
  ┃     ┗ html (symlink to myexistingsite.com/html)
  ┃
  ┗ myexistingsite.com
        ┗ html
             ┗ newfestival
             ┗ otherstuff
```

Then when people go to www.newfestivals.com they see all of the content from myexisting site, just as if it was all under newfestivals

Comment: Ah, can't do that, I'm afraid. newfestivals.com is just a registered domain, it does not have its own storage space, so I can't create a symlink under it to point to myexistingsite.com/html. That's why I wanted to use my existing site storage space to redirect newfestivals.com to. If I had bought storage space for newfestivals.com I would have created the newfestivals.com site normally, without too much hassle.

Comment: hm.. who are you using? I know with my host at least I can point as many names to my hosting as I like, called "add-on domains" but if you are restricted to one then that is tough indeed.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I have changed my strategy and forked some more money for storage, no need to redirect or tweak address bar anymore.

Comment: to answer your question, I am using a company called Serverplan