# Executing MATLAB from Bash

Tags: bash, matlab

I've been trying to work on opening/executing MATLAB from bash (I'm using Terminal, specifically). However, despite numerous attempts at troubleshooting, I have been unable to do it.

Running the "`matlab`" command gives me the error:

> -bash: matlab: command not found

A cursory Google search suggested it could be an issue of my local bin, but my bin looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin:
  total used in directory 16 available 208047788
  drwxr-xr-x  4 alifarhat  wheel  136 Jul 22 11:30 .
  drwxr-xr-x  3 alifarhat  wheel  102 Jan 22 01:56 ..
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 alifarhat  wheel   29 Jul 22 11:30 matlab -> /usr/local/matlab6/bin/matlab
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 alifarhat  wheel   26 Jul 22 11:30 mex -> /usr/local/matlab6/bin/mex
```

Which seems to indicate that matlab is talking to the bin.

If it helps, when I cd into /usr/local and then ls, the only directory/item in there at all is "bin". Could this have something to do with it? How can I fix it if it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `PATH` issues. Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`?
Try

```
 ~$ echo $PATH
```

What do you see?

If `/usr/local/bin` is not part of your `$PATH` you can add it:

```
 ~$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then try and run `matlab` from shell

**EDIT:**
Based on [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571212/executing-matlab-from-bash/31571312?noredirect=1#comment51097827_31571312) it seems like `matlab` executable is not located at `/usr/local/matlab6/bin`. Therefore, you can either

1. Add `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/` to path:

   ~$ export PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin:$PATH

or

2. Replace the broken symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` (you might need `root` privileges for this). See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux) for more details.

Comment: echo $PATH gives me "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: **/usr/local/bin**: /usr/X11/bin"

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics if you `~$ ls /usr/local/matlab6/bin/` what do you see?

Comment: No such file or directory.

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics this means the sym links in `/usr/local/bin` are broken and pointing nowhere. Are you sure Matlab is installed on your machine? is it possible someone uninstalled it/removed it?

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics try locating matlab `~$ find /usr -name "matlab" -type f` what can you see?

Comment: I've used MATLAB on this machine (without going through the command line) before and it clearly works, so it's definitely on the machine.

Comment: And I see nothing when executing that line. I may as well have just clicked enter.

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics it's definitely not in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/matlab6/bin`...

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics try expanding the search: `~$ find / -name "*matlab*" -type f` - it might take a while.

Comment: I think it found them in "Applications"

Comment: Executing "find /Applications -name "matlab" -type f" gave me "/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab"

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics good for you! now you can either replace the broken sym-links in `/usr/local/bin` or add the correct folder in `Applications` to your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in the correct directory, you should execute the command:

```
    ./matlab
```

instead of just typing matlab.

Comment: There's an issue with finding "the correct directory" as you can see from [these comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571212/executing-matlab-from-bash/31571312?noredirect=1#comment51097544_31571312).