# Installing Grunt on RedHat

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, redhat

I'm trying to create a red hat build server and need to install grunt globally.
Running: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

I tried: sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
However, this gived the error:

```
Error: user admin not allowed to access it : grunt-cli
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:308:14)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:246:65)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:236:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1142:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1096:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What commands do i need to run to be able to install this? Im running as root.

Comment: You can try to install it without -g and symlink it to your /usr/bin/ folder or sth. Might not be the best solution, but it could work.

Comment: How would i do that? i.e what command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux