# Accessing a directory

Tags: directory

I go to my working directories by typing *cd directory1/dir2/dir3/../* always. Is there any shortcut that I can make to go to my working directory instead of typing all these every time ?

Comment: How about using a symbolic link?

Answer (score 0):

You can do symbolic link to the dir.
I.e. 
in -s /path/to/dir/to/link link_name
Then you can do
cd link_name

Answer (score 0):

You can try and search for "how to create symbolic/hard/soft links in linux". Below are some examples that may help you.

[create symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux)

[Difference between hard and soft links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link)

[How to create hard links](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-hard-links-with-ln-command/)

[Create soft link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/)

Answer (score 0):

For windows you can create batch file with following code.

```
cd "c:\Documents and Settings\etc\etc"
start .
```

For Linux

You can use the environment variable CDPATH

Suppose you want to go to  cd /usr/directory1/dir2/dir3/dir4/

```
export CDPATH=.:/usr/directory1/dir2/dir3
```

then typing cd dir4 would take you /usr/directory1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ 
assuming there's no directory named dir4 within the current directory