# Two versions of Java (1.8.0_66 and 1.7.0_67) coexist on my Centos 6.4 , how to delete the old 1.7?

Tags: java, centos, version

The old version that i had was java `1.7.0_67` . To run a program i was obliged to install a new version `1.8.0_66`. I installed it from here http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/# but when i came to the last step which is the verification of the version of java i found 1.7.0_67.

It means that the system is still working with the old version.
I want to delete the old one and work with java 1.8.0_66 which is logically installed somewhere in the machine but not taken into consideration.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i'm working on Centos Redhat , linux

Comment: if you delete the old version it doesn't mean that the new version will work, the system should be able to find a new version executable file to run your program.

Comment: Okey, but what to do? when i type the command "which java" it gives me the path of the old version. I just want it to point to the path of the new version. Simple but i don't really know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You should create a symlink to the new version of `java` executable and put it into `/usr/bin`. The way is `which` command works is to find the first available path of the file defined by the system environment variable. The one I suggested to use is very popular among UNIX/Linux systems. You could provide the exact path to the `java` intolation folder. `cd /usr/bin; ln -s /path/to/javasdk/bin/java java`. If you like to know how to create a symlink, this post would be helpful [How to symlink a file in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1951742/573032).