# Symbolic link: Current directory

Tags: bash, symlink

I have got a question were I have to create a symbolic link named "new" to file /test/test1/test2. The current command I have is this:

```
ln -s /test/test1/test2 /new
```

I am not if there is a specific command which will create it in the current directory? any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: See: [How to symlink a file in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1951742/3776858)

Comment: This belongs in [SE *Nix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Even though I doubt they'd answer it there. Seems like a classic case of RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the leading `/` in the target name.

```
ln -s /test/test1/test2 new
```

If you want to be explicit, use `.` as the name of the current directory:

```
ln -s /test/test1/test2 ./new
```