# not fully redirecting stdout in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to store stdout&stderr into $log and $script_log.
$log has all other process log so used >> 
$script_log needs only log from set_flag.sh and update.sh.

```
set_flag.sh 2>&1 >> $log | tee -a $log > $script_log 
update.sh 2>&1 >> $log | tee -a $log >> $script_log
```

$log is fine. I can see all process logs from both set_flag.sh and update.sh but somehow $script_log has log from set_flag but partial log from update.sh.
Not sure why....

Can anybody explain and help me out?

Thanks,

Comment: why write to $log at all? why not just `script | tee > $script_log`? tee already does the splitting for you. there's no need to cache to a file, have tee read from that file, only to write out to ANOTHER file.

Comment: @MarcB `tee` reads from stdin, and all passed file parameters are output files.

Comment: That said, I don't get how `tee` can receive any input at all, given that input redirection is done prior to piping.

Comment: @Siguza `script 2>&1 >> log` is not the same as `script >> log 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
set_flag.sh 2>&1 | tee    $script_log >>$log
update.sh   2>&1 | tee -a $script_log >>$log
```

`$log` was present in your command twice, and that is probably not needed for the question you posted (all stdout+stderr into `$log`, and only stdout+stderr of `set_flag.sh` and `update.sh` in `$script_log`).

Comment: This is what I was thinking piping stderr and stdout to `tee` and letting that handle the splitting to log and script_log.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want **stdout & stderr** of `set_flag.sh` and `update.sh` into `$log` and `$script_log`.

If that is the case, redirect script outputs to `$log` and [create a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux) with name `$script_log` and make that point to your `$log`.

This way, you can save diskspace [no duplicate files] and keep `$log` and `$script_log` exactly same.