# Symlink not being created

Tags: bash, fedora, symlink

I'm running Fedora on a laptop with a small SSD and large HDD. I've got the OS installed on the SSD and my data on the HDD.

All my files are located at `/run/media/kennedy/data/Kennedy`

What I had before (and want again) is a symlink from `/home/kennedy` to that location. That way I'm not messing with actual `/home`, but when I am in `/home` as normal user, all my things are easily accessed and stored with plenty of space. Right now `/home/kennedy` has the standard directories; desktop, documents, downloads, and so forth. No files worth worrying about.

So I opened a shell, logged in as su, and entered

`ln -s /home/kennedy /run/media/kennedy/data/Kennedy`

expecting that when I `cd /home/kennedy` and `ls`, I would see all my lovelies. Instead, I see that standard folders and nothing more. Whisky Tango Foxtrot, over.

edit to add: I'm pretty sure the permissions are right, but only pretty sure. How do I check and correct that (if off)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reverse the arguments:

```
ln -s /run/media/kennedy/data/Kennedy /home/kennedy
```

This will:

- run successfully if `/home/kennedy` doesn't exist (`kennedy` would be the new symlink)
- fail if `/home/kennedy` exists and it is not a directory (symlink or a regular file); need add `-f` flag in such a case - `ls -sf ...`
- if `/home/kennedy` is a directory, then the symlink will be created as `/home/kennedy/kennedy`

See this related post: [How to symlink a file in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. `/home/kennedy` is not a directory I created, it is the directory created for the user "kennedy" so that, when logged in as kennedy and looking at `/home` in the GUI you actually see the contents of `/home/kennedy`. What I want to happen is that when the user looks at that directory, they see the contents of `/run/media/kennedy/data/Kennedy`. I don't want to open `/home/kennedy` and see the symlink. the directory `/home/kennedy` should be nothing more than a window to the HDD directory. Do I need to remove the directory kennedy and create the symlink?

Comment: I am not sure what content is already there in `/home/kennedy`.  So, it will be more prudent to do `mv /home/kennedy /home/kennedy.old` rather than removing it.

Answer (score 3):

You have the command backwards, it should be:

```
ln -s /run/media/kennedy/data/Kennedy kennedy
```

Invoke the command while you are in your `/home` directory, then you should be set.