# Create symbolic link fails in Docker for Windows, it's not supported yet?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, symlink

I have a docker container running Ubuntu Server. I am running Docker for Windows and I have the following version of Docker and Docker Compose respectively installed:

```
> docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build f963d76f

> docker -v
Docker version 17.03.1-ce-rc1, build 3476dbf
```

This is what I have tried so far without success:

```
// The dojo linked file exists so I've tried to update it as per this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1951752/719427)
> docker exec -it dockeramp_webserver_1 ln -sf /var/www/html/externals/dojo /var/www/html/externals/public_html/js/dojo
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/html/externals/public_html/js/dojo': No such file or directory

// I have deleted the previous linked file and then I tried to create a new one
> docker exec -it dockeramp_webserver_1 ln -s /var/www/html/externals/dojo /var/www/html/externals/public_html/js/dojo
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/html/externals/public_html/js/dojo': No such file or directory

// removed the directory name from the link name
> docker exec -it dockeramp_webserver_1 ln -s /var/www/html/externals/dojo /var/www/html/externals/public_html/js    
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/html/externals/public_html/js': No such file or directory
```

Because the error keep saying the directory doesn't exists then I've checked if the error is right or wrong:

```
> docker exec -u www-data -it dockeramp_webserver_1 ls -la /var/www/html/externals/dojo
total 80
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Mar 25 15:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Mar 25 15:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Mar 25 15:09 dijit
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Mar 25 15:09 dojo
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Mar 25 15:09 dojox
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     0 Mar 25 15:09 mmi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 74047 Mar 25 15:09 tundra.css

> docker exec -u www-data -it dockeramp_webserver_1 ls -la /var/www/html/public_html/js
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 26 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 15:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7123 Mar 25 15:09 jquery.PrintArea.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6141 Mar 25 15:11 quoteit_delegate_search.js
```

They both exists so ... what I am missing here? It's not supported in Windows just yet? I have found the development team added something called [mfsymlinks](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-for-windows-1121-2016-09-16-stable) in a previous version than mine.

Comment: i have met this before: cannot make linux symbol link in win10 bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is telling you that `/var/www/html/externals/public_html` does not exist. You only showed that the `/var/www/html/externals/dojo` and `/var/www/html/public_html/js` folders exist. I believe this is a simple typo in your commands.

Comment: you are right, I made a mistake `externals/public_html` does not exists and for that reason the error, I was frustrated yesterday and wasn't reading the error message properly, apologies