# error while running python command on ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

bash: /home/asif/anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory

i am getting this error while running python command on ubuntu terminal

Comment: does the file exists ?

Comment: It seems the anaconda installation of python is missing, navigate to the directory mentioned and check if the installation is present. Reinstalling the anaconda framework oughta fix the problem if it was due to broken installation

Comment: i just uninstalled anaconda

Answer (score 1):

try the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/asif/anaconda/bin/python
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this as your mixing the two. This could be harder to troubleshoot further issues down the road between system python and Anaconda. Anaconda/bin/python should be prepended to the PATh so that it is selected before system python anyways.

Answer (score 0):

try to check python is installed or not, and check which version of python you are using,

```
$ which python
```

Comment: This answer should help you locate python, you then can create a symbolic link if your script expects python to be somewhere else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux