# How to create a symlink for image folders in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an application and deployed in a server. I also have a functionality of generating QR codes and save them into storage symlink.

**Here's my server scaffolding:**

[image]

In a `local` directory I have all source Laravel code. Other files are from `public` directory.

How to create a symlink in the server folder? What's the workaround?

**Here's the example of doing via calling a PHP script:**

```
symlink('/home/local/storage/app/public', 'storage');
```

Comment: Windows server? Good luck (I mean it).

Comment: @Kyslik nope, my local machine is on Windows, but the server is on Linux :) Do u have any idea?

Comment: Shared hosting? Do you have ssh access? if so just google around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux

Comment: @Kyslik `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink` - in here from where I should type a path? from the root directory of server or what?

Comment: Well since you are using absolute paths (path starts with `/`) you can type it from wherever, just use correct user eg (apache/nginx user). Also there is a command within artisan to make storage link - `artisan storage:link`, not sure if you need that.

Comment: @Kyslik on my local machine I used `artisan` command to create a `symlink` and it is all perfect. I have some troubles with the server.

Comment: @Kyslik What if I don't have ssh access? How should I solve the problem?