# Placing logfiles in multiple directories Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have a quick question.
We want to put the asterisk logs in multiple directories.

Is this possible with an asterisk server?

We were thinking about something like this.
(our example)

```
astlogdir => /var/log/asterisk, /var/log/remote-asterisk
```

right now it is this;

```
astlogdir => /var/log/asterisk
```

Anybody got any ideas if this is possible and what would be the right way?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use a [symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux). The logger sees the link as a file, and the file system is responsible for writing the data to the linked location instead. The link is not a copy of the log, but just a pointer to another path on the file system.

Go to your logging folder:

```
cd /var/log/asterisk/
```

Make a link to a new file in /var/log/asterisk-remote (adjust the target path to your needs).

```
sudo ln -s /var/log/asterisk-remote/other-log /var/log/asterisk/link-log
```

View the link:

```
ls -ll
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Oct  2 16:12 link-log -> /var/log/asterisk-remote/other-log
```

Then in `/etc/asterisk/logger.conf` just add the link's name (with whatever types of log messages you want it to receive):

```
[logfiles]
messages => notice,warning,error
link-log => notice,warning,error
```

Be sure to reload your config to apply the changes (this is done in the Asterisk CLI, which you can access via `asterisk -r` in the shell):

`core reload`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You just have open logger.c and write needed code

No, at current moment it not do so, nobody need it.

As second option you always can do symlink