# Manage Laravel project remotely in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I have a Laravel project and I have uploaded it in the `public_html` folder in the hosting. Then I added the `server` in the PhpStorm project and it is working fine and no need to upload all files again and again, I can only upload changed files automatically. I was able to access the Laravel website as `abc.com/public`.

Then I searched to skip the `public` from the url. I followed the process and place all my Laravel files in the root path, before the `public_html` then I only placed the `public` folder of Laravel to the `public_html`. Now I want to know how I can manage this project in PhpStorm remotely? I mean changes should upload automatically.

Comment: I suggest you use bitbucket or github.

Comment: @DerekPollard I already have attached that, but I want to submit changes live to the remote server.

Comment: @DerekPollard It is really duplicating effort to upload whole project again and again to test specific functionalities on server.

Comment: You could create a github hook that listens for changes and then pulls them down to the server

Comment: Literally, all you have to do is run `git pull` and all the changes are transferred.

Comment: Can yo give me any link where are these instructions?

Answer (score 0):

As Derek suggested you should use version control Github or Bitbucket.

Or you can create sym link to avoid multiple occurrences of your code and remove public from URL

Your previous directory structure:
- /root
    - public_html
        - laravel_project

What you can do is:

- /root

  - laravel_project
  - public_html

    - sym_link -> /root/laravel_project/public

Use these commands

cd public_html

ln -s /root/laravel_project/Public sym_link

In this way there will only be one code base and do changes in that with your IDE

Comment: Github is for saving, or version control. How it can be work with live project as on hosting?

Comment: Github is for version control. You can create a repository over github and push all your code to the respository and clone for first time (or pull after that) on server.

You can understand from this link : https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Comment: Do you really understand what I'm asking? I have deployed my laravel project on hosting There I want to change.

Comment: If you don't want to use version control, then In Phpstorm you can add remote server with root path also access our files with that.

Comment: But files are divided on two places, read my question please.

Comment: To manage that, you can create symlink, In this way only one file need to be changed and automatically it wil reflect in both places.

Please refer to this link on how to create symlink:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux