# How can I include file without extension in pug?

Tags: pug

From docs:

> If no file extension is given, .pug is automatically appended to the file name.

However, I need to include a system file without extension:

```
include .browserslistrc
```

Pug tries to include `.browserslistrc.pug`, not `.browserslistrc`. How can I include this file without creating a symbolic link?

Comment: You can't.  Pug only includes .pug files, as the docs indicate.

Comment: @Graham pug may include files as plain text: https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html#including-plain-text

Comment: Then it looks like you have found a bug, probably best to report it on the github issues page and delete this question.

Comment: @Graham it's a good question and may help future SO users with the same question—why delete?

Comment: Because it can't be answered.  See this (and dozens of other meta discussions): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346666/has-sos-attitude-towards-bug-reports-changed

Comment: @Graham I will try to report it as a bug.
But now the question seems to me relevant. In addition, the question contains a solution, albeit not the best (creating a symbolic link with any extension).

Comment: Up to you in the end, if you feel that creating the symbolic link is the answer then you should go ahead and post it as an answer so this question is flagged as having a solution.  You may also want to add some more descriptive text to the title such as "no extension"

Comment: issue: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/3116

Answer (score 0):

Solution option (**possibly suitable only for Unix-like systems**):

You can create a [symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux) to a file without an extension by adding an any extension. Example:

```
ln -s .browserslistrc .browserslistrc.txt
```

Windows also supports symbolic links, but I have not tested this solution there. Probably, this solution will not be cross-platform.