# Pycharm: virtually change name of package

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, pythonpath

I have a python project, with a source tree like:

```
|-src
|  |- module1
|  |  |- tests
|  |- module2
|  |  |- tests
|- ...
```

It will be deployed to a docker as package `mypkg`, in a way I cannot change -- transparently adding the `mypkg` folder and `__init__.py`.

Inside my code I generally import things with `import mypkg.module1` or `from mypkg.module2 import xyz`. However, since there is no `mypkg` folder (and `__init__.py`) under `src`, pycharm does not recognize these imports and reports `Unresolved reference` errors, and is not able to run pytest against any tests (even though they are not relying  on any resource only available within the docker).

Right now for tests I change the imports in the tests from `import mypkg.module1` to `import module1`, run the tests in pycharm, fix bugs, change it back and commit. But as you can imagine this is error prone and annoying.

Is there any way I can tell pycharm or the python environment (maybe `$PYTHONPATH` to recognize my package as `mypkg` and act accordingly?

I'm using python 3.5+, exclusively (if that matters).

Comment: So, is there a reason why your project structure doesn't match the way the package is installed? Why does is `mypkg` parent package get created during the installation? *Of course* that's going to cause problems. Whose idea was that?

Comment: Not mine :) -- but I have to live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for both python *and* your IDE to correctly resolve your imports, you *will* need to create a directory named `mypkg` that contains `module1` and `module2`. I can think of two ways to go about this:

## 1. The correct solution: Fixing the project structure and installation

Rather than creating the `mypkg` directory during the installation process, have a real `mypkg` directory inside your `src` directory:

```
|-src
|  |- mypkg
|  |  |- module1
|  |  |  |- tests
|  |  |- module2
|  |  |  |- tests
|- ...
```

(Side note: your tests probably shouldn't be *inside* your packages. You don't want to ship those, or let the user import them, do you?)

## 2. The workaround: Symlinks

Create a `mypkg` directory somewhere on your PYTHONPATH. Then create symlinks to `module1` and `module2`. ([How to create symlinks on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/255731/make-a-hard-link-without-extra-programs-in-windows-7), [How to create symlinks on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux))

In your project directory:

```
|-src
|  |- module1
|  |  |- tests
|  |- module2
|  |  |- tests
|- ...
```

Somewhere on your PYTHONPATH:

```
|- mypkg
|  |- module1 -> path_to_your_project/src/module1
|  |- module2 -> path_to_your_project/src/module2
```