# Laravel: show images which are outside of root directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, symlink

I need to display a series of images that are outside the root directory.

I've been reading about creating a symbolic link but I can't get my head around it at all.

In the *filesystems.php* file, the disk pointing to that directory is:

```
'communication' => [
    driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/var/www/communication',
],

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

What I think I should make is a symbolic link pointing from "/var/www/communication" to "app/public" but it's not clear to me at all.

Please, could someone help me or guide me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think that with "create a symbolic link", they mean to do it at the operating system level, and not to something in laravel. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951752/7498116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app/public` you need to create a symbolic link to `/var/www/communication`

```
ln -s /var/www/communication communication
```

Your `app/public/communication` now points to `/var/www/communication`.

```
'communication' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('communication'),
]
```